# close jquery dialog when click outsite

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have dialog and now I want to close dialog when I click outsite dialog or move mouse out dialog,I do not know why it can not work, here is my code:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Title of the document</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script text="langue/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".popup").click(function(){   
        $( "#dialog-message" ).dialog({
                     modal: true,
                     title: 'Detail',
                     buttons: {
                     Ok: function() {
                         $( this ).dialog( "close" );
                         }
                     },                                      
                }); 
    }); 

    $(".ui-widget-overlay").click (function () {
     $("#dialog-message").dialog( "close" );
    });
});
</script>
<body>
<div id="dialog-message"> 
</div>
<a href="#" class="popup">click</a>
</body>
</html>
```

thankyou very much

Comment: Try creating a jsfiddle!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because the selector ".ui-widget-overlay" does not yet exists in that context. You need to wait before it exists. You see, it is not created until you actually open the dialog.

One quick fix, is to apply the click event to the document, and filter out the ".ui-widget-overlay" selector, as such:

```
$(document).on('click', ".ui-widget-overlay", function(){
    $("#dialog-message").dialog( "close" );
});
```

Comment: thankyou,it works,in any ways,can we work for closed dialog when we move mouse out popup ?

Comment: Sure! Just change `'click'` to `'click mouseleave'`. This way it is triggered on both the `click` event, and the `mouseleave` event!

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).mouseup(function(e) {
  var alert_box = $(".ui-widget-overlay");
  if (alert_box.has(e.target).length === 0)
     $("#dialog-message").dialog("close");
});
```

The above code will close the dialog box when you click outside the modal box

Comment: thankyou,it works,in any ways,can we work for closed dialog when we move mouse out popup ?

Comment: try this.

$(document).on('mouseout', '.ui-widget-overlay', function(e) {$("#dialog-message").dialog("close");})